# How to group json models in THREE.js?

Tags: json, three.js

I wish to group loaded json models in THREE.js but am getting an error...

```
THREE.Object3D.add: object not an instance of THREE.Object3D
```

I'm using the example code of...

```
var group = new THREE.Object3D();
```

and then...

```
group.add(model1);
group.add(model2);
```

I load model1 and model2 previously - these render out fine when I add them to the scene individually, but when I add the group I get the error...

```
scene.add( group );
```

I've tried a combination of different techniques such as THREE.Mesh() or adding json models to other json models eg. model1.add(model2).

R72

Answer (score 0):

The problem is asynchronous loading of the models - trying to perform actions on the models before they are loaded.

```
group = new THREE.Mesh(); //global to add transforms
var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();

jsonLoader.load( "model1.json", function(geometry,materials) {
    var mesh = createMesh(geometry,materials); //function to create generic mesh properties
    group.add(mesh);
});

jsonLoader.load( "model2.json", function(geometry,materials) {
    var mesh = createMesh(geometry,materials); //function to create generic mesh properties
    group.add(mesh);
});

scene.add( group );

function createMesh( geometry, materials ) 
{
    var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    return mesh;
};
```

Comment: Why use the Mesh class for the group?